# How to get Android Studio AVD connect with OBS-Camera orOBS Virtual Camera

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to use OBS Virtual Camera or OBS-Camera ( OBS Virtualcam 2.0.5 plugin) to work with Android Studio to feed in high resolution video to a Virtual Android Device.

(If there are suggested easy work arounds or other emulators that would support this let me know as I've seen most have resolution options locked down or no obvious way to edit them)

```
emulator @AVD_NAME_FROM_LIST -webcam-list
```

AVD edit only shows webcam0, editting it manually from webcam0 -> webcam5 hasn't yielded any results either.

These cameras are detected by all other applications, browsers, windows camera app doesn't detect it.

Any solution that might allow or alternative would be appreciated thanks.